# How can I automatically bring the Output Path to a new Visual Studio Configuration on Create and Copy?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, transformation, nopcommerce

I am working on a NOPCommerce project, and trying to set up transforms for a QA and UAT site.  I created a QA and UST configuration, and selected "Copy setting from:" debug.  However, instead of using the debug Output Path for each project, it uses "bin/QA".  I know I can change these either through editing the .csproj or through VS< but there are literally dozens of projects where this causes issues, and they do not use one default directory.  Is there any way to get a new configuration to copy over the Output Path?

Thanks,
Mike